# Plotting Log Cumulative Hazard Plots in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to generate a log-cumulative hazard plot as part of an assessment of PH assumption. Here is my code to generate the plot:

```
library(survival)

# Load the lung cancer survival data
lung <- lung


surv_object <- Surv(lung$time, lung$status)
survfitobj <- survfit(surv_object ~ lung$sex)

plot(survfit(surv_object ~ lung$sex), 
     col=c("black", "red"),
     fun="cloglog")
```

However, the X-axis is not on the log scale? How does one plot the x-axis on the log scale? Like this example here: [ResearchGate example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Log-cumulative-Hazard-Plots-of-Overall-Survival-and-Progression-free-Survival-of-Eribulin_fig1_336707509)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `fun=="cumhaz"` argument in the `plot.survfit`  function from the `survival` package (first plot), like below.

The same argument is implemented in the `ggsurvplot` from the `survminer` package (second plot)

```r
library(survival)
fit=survfit(Surv(time, status==2) ~ sex, data = lung)
plot(fit,fun="cumhaz")

library(survminer)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, fun = "cumhaz")
```

[image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note when you use the "cloglog" you are plotting complimentary log-log survival plot (f(y) = log(-log(y)) along with log scale for the x-axis)
see ?plot.survfit

and note below the x axis ticks are in days but you can see that ticks are doubling at each time (500 days and 1000 days are closer than in the first plot) that is the log re-scaling

```r
plot(fit,fun="cloglog")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Both axes are now not on the log scale?

Comment: No not in log scale, you can see the x axis in log scale in the third plot. note the ticks values